# hibernate-ogm-5.1.0 final with wildfly 10 neo4j module error

Tags: neo4j, hibernate-ogm

I want to configure hibernate-ogm with wildfly 10+ neo4j but getting this error. Can any one help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the Hibernate OGM modules and unpack them the Wildfly folder. Follow the instructions in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-configuration-jbossmodule

In short:

1. [Download the WildFly modules](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-ogm/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-ogm-modules-5.1.0.Final-wildfly-10-dist.zip/download)
2. Unpack the modules in the HOME of your WildFly server

If you have alredy done this, check that the modules are in the right place under WILDFLY_HOME/modules/org/hibernate/ogm